# Crystal reports parameters window

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Is there any way to access to the parameters default window of crystal reports?
In the same topic, this window prompt twice every time i run my reports. I serach the solution in the net but i can't fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, why do you want to access the parameter default window?

Comment: The second prompt most likely for a sub report you need to link the parameters.  Right click on the subreport and modify subreport links.

Comment: No i have no subreport!